# How to output this json {},{} with php?

Tags: php, json, extjs

I was unable to output this:

```
[{"title":"London","foo":"bar"},{"title":"Istanbul","foo":"bar"}]
```

I cannot make comma here: `},{`

I can output this `[{"title":"London","foo":"bar"}]` but not the first example.

Comment: That's valid JSON. How do you know it's the comma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will produce the desired output:

```
$data = array(
    array("title" => "London",
          "foo" => "bar"
    ), 
    array("title" => "Istanbul",
          "foo" => "bar"
    )
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Make sure you create your arrays correctly. For more information have a look at the [documentation for `json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).